# correct syntax for feeding lat/long to geofield_latlon in migration

Tags: 8, migrations

I have a drupal 6 site I wish to migrate to drupal 8.

My configuration includes:

**migrate_plus.migration.upgrade_d6_node_complete_club.yml**

```
# ...
class: Drupal\node\Plugin\migrate\D6NodeTranslation
field_plugin_method: null
cck_plugin_method: null
# ...
source:
  plugin: d6_node_complete
  node_type: club
# ...
process:
  # ...
  field_latitude:
    -
      plugin: get
      source: field_latitude
  field_longitude:
    -
      plugin: get
      source: field_longitude
# ...
```

When I run `drush migrate:import`, the `club` content is correctly migrated.

I wish the drupal 8 `club` content to include a geofield.

Following https://www.drupal.org/node/2866147, I modified the configuration to be:

```
# ...
process:
  # ...
  field_latitude:
    -
      plugin: get
      source: field_latitude
  field_longitude:
    -
      plugin: get
      source: field_longitude
  field_geofield:
      plugin: geofield_latlon
      source:
        - field_latitude
        - field_longitude
# ...
```

I manually added (using the web ui) a new `field_geofield` to the drupal 8 `club` content-type.
Then I did `drush migrate:rollback upgrade_d6_node_complete_club`
and `drush migrate:import upgrade_d6_node_complete_club`.

However, the drupal 8 `club` new geofield always just has latitude:longitude coordinates of 1:1.

---

I looked at [`web/modules/contrib/geofield/src/Plugin/migrate/process/GeofieldLatLon.php`](https://github.com/drupalprojects/geofield/blob/3c0c5e3c86e488343e748ef503cb250542cc7c28/src/Plugin/migrate/process/GeofieldLatLon.php#L22) and saw:

```
  public function transform($value, MigrateExecutableInterface $migrate_executable, Row $row, $destination_property) {
    $value = array_map('floatval', $value);
    list($lat, $lon) = $value;
```

I added a `var_dump($value)` at the top. It shows that with the process YAML as above, `transform()` receives `$value` like:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["value"]=>
      string(9) "50.854334"
      ["delta"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["value"]=>
      string(9) "-0.553837"
      ["delta"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
  }
}
```

I don't need the geofield_latlon plugin anywhere else for the migration, so I could just prefix `transform()` with:

```
$value = array_map(function($k){return $k[0]['value'];}, $value);
```

Is there a way to adjust just the YAML, without having to write any code, so that geofield_latlon receives its data in the correct format?

I feel that using something like the [extract plugin](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21migrate%21src%21Plugin%21migrate%21process%21Extract.php/class/Extract) ought to be possible but am having difficulty finding any good description of the semantics of migrate YML config files.

Comment: check this out https://www.berramou.com/blog/migrate-location-filed-drupal-6-geofield-filed-drupal-8

Comment: @berramou Thanks for the code example. I've amended my question - the issue seems not to be getting the field data, it is how to pass it correctly into geofield_latlon

Comment: I opened a bug at: https://www.drupal.org/project/geofield/issues/3163198

Answer (score 0):

this may be too late. But I had a similar issue. The latittude and longitude was not getting set in the geofield.  I had named the fields coming in from source as lat and lng. So I had:

```
field_event_geo:
    -
      plugin: geofield_latlon
      source:
        - lat
        - lng
```

Looking at the transform() function in modules/contrib/geofield/src/Plugin/migrate/process/GeoField.php, I realized that it was looking for value['lon'].  So I changed my migrate yml to:

```
field_event_geo:
    -
      plugin: geofield_latlon
      source:
        - lat
        - lon
```

(after changing the source field from lng to lon ofcourse) and it sets the geofield's lat,lon correctly.

Comment: Thanks Yes, I've completed my migration but maybe your suggestion will help someone else :-)